# how to fix compiler error on VS2019 with /std:c++20

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

Following code compiles fine with c++14 or c++17 mode and also in gcc c++20 mode. In 16.11.4 and c++20 mode it fails:

```
<source>(20): error C2039: '_ns': is not a member of 'ns2'
<source>(6): note: see declaration of 'ns2'
<source>(18): note: This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'ns::Duration ns::Duration::fromNanoseconds(const T) noexcept'
```

Has anybody an ideo what goes wrong. using the /permissive fixes it, but don't know why...

```
namespace ns
{
  struct Duration;
}

namespace ns2
{
   int operator"" _ns(unsigned long long int value) noexcept
   {
     return 0;
   }
}
namespace ns
{
struct Duration
{
  template <typename T>
  static  Duration fromNanoseconds(const T value) noexcept
  {
    ns2::operator"" _ns(value); //error C2039: '_ns': is not a member of 'ns2'
    return {};
  }
};
}

int main()
{
  ns::Duration::fromNanoseconds(1);
}
```

Comment: "how to fix?" and "what is going on?" are slightly different questions. You already know how to fix, no?

Comment: Did you mean `/permissive-`? This is spelled `permissive minus` and makes the compiler more strict, and also more standard compliant.

Comment: /permissive makes it working but that's not a fix, more a workaround. I want to know, why it does not compile without /permissive. I already leanred, that /permissive- is implicitly set if using /std:c++20

Comment: what is the compiler error?

Comment: Can be seen in the code above: //error C2039: '_ns': is not a member of 'ns2'

Comment: `int operator"" _ns` what exactly is this? Is that an operator overloading construct that I don't know of?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him it's a user defined literal